# undefined index error found in file upload

Tags: php

i am using this code to upload any file but it's making error as undefined index file
and file size too big as in die.........

Please help.....

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['up_load']))
{
if(!file_exists('upload'))
{
mkdir('upload');
}

$userfile=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$targetfile='upload'."/".basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

$filesize=$_FILES['file']['size'];


if($filesize<2000000000)
{
$i=move_uploaded_file($userfile,$targetfile) or die("File was tooo big!");

if($i)
{
echo "file uploaded!";
}
}

}
?>


<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="file_upload.php" enctype="multipart/form_data">
<input type="file" name="file" />
<input type="submit" name="up_load" value="upload!"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

is it becoz of my php ini file.
or i'm missing something plz help.

Comment: Which line is returning this error?

Answer (score 0):

`check php configuraion`

```
file_uploads    "1"
upload_max_filesize     "2M"
post_max_size   "8M"
max_file_uploads    20
```